# Bank Exercise in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

First time post here, recent new user. I've searched for this question because I know the all too common "Bank program" questions, however I couldn't find an answer (that I understood atleast) to my question.

I know about the homework rule, but I've literally been stuck on this for over a week for an online course i'm taking. I feel like I understand it but I am missing something that won't allow me to piece it together. I'm suppose to make a bank form that allows an initial deposit, deposit and withdrawal in Visual Studio that outputs the balance updates to a listbox. I easily made the graphics part, I have 3 textboxes, 3 buttons and a listbox (for the balance output). I have it so I parsed the textboxes to allow my numbers to be considered doubles instead of string by default, I also have it so I can output the numbers into the listbox upon clicking the deposit button (listBox.Items.Add(blahblahblah). I'm suppose to use a constructor  to set the initial deposit but I'm stuck on how to do that. This is the homework..

**"Create a new Windows Forms Application project named BankForm. Add controls that allow the user to enter an initial deposit, and a button to set the deposit. This initial deposit will create an instance of the BankAccount class, calling a constructor that has the initial deposit as its sole parameter. Then have another set of controls that allow the user to make a deposit or withdrawal. Each time a deposit or withdrawal is made, including the initial deposit, output the activity and the balance to a ListBox control.
For this project, the class you make should have accessors to get the balance, and methods to deposit and withdraw funds. The class instance will need to be a private member variable of your Form. You could create it using syntax like private BankAccount bankForm. Then, when the user clicks on the initial deposit button, in the button click event, use the new keyword to create the bankForm object. So, if the initial deposit was $100, you would create the object using syntax like bankForm = new BankAccount(100.0).
"**

What I did was made a separate class from the form called BankAccount. Then I'm trying to figure out how to set a constructor for the initial deposit which I did, but how do I make it go to the actual form so the user can enter in the initial deposit textbox and then have the constructor take on that value?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BankForm
{
    class BankAccount
    {
        double _initialDeposit { get; set; }
        double _deposit { get; set; }
        double _withdrawl { get; set; }
        double _balance { get; set; }

        public BankAccount()
        {

        }

        public BankAccount(double initDeposit)
        {
            this._initialDeposit = initDeposit;
        }

        public double Initial
        {
            get { return _initialDeposit; }
            set { _initialDeposit = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

^ That is all I have so far for the BankAccount class, I just made the private variables then tried making the constructor to take an initial deposit value, but when I go to the form and type BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount() I don't know how to set the button click for the initial deposit to go into the () for the constructor.. I screwed this up on purpose so you can see what i'm doing. On the form i'm trying to add together the initial deposit with the normal deposit but they are both in private void buttons and can't access each other's information. I'm going crazy god damn. Obviously I am completely new to programming and I've downloaded a ton of books and am learning, but this one project has me so confused I don't know why. Every other project has gone smooth so far.

```
namespace BankForm
{
    public partial class BankForm : Form
    {

        public BankForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void setDepositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double setInitial = double.Parse(setDepositTextBox.Text);
            BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(setInitial);
            listBox.Items.Add(setInitial);

        }

        private void depositBalanceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double setDepo = double.Parse(depositBalanceTextBox.Text);
            BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(setDepo + setDepositTextBox.Text);

        }

        private void withdrawBalanceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                      
        }

        private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }             
    }
}
```

I know this post is stupid and long winded but if anyone can give me any hints even I will be forever grateful.

Comment: TL;DR; - please make your question small and concrete. Remove all "new here", "thank you" and other random text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. :) I'm glad you showed effort but this place is not a chatty type of place. We don't like questions that are chatty. All that's needed really is the code and explanation of what it does and your needs. Other than that just remove anything that doens't help this question.

Comment: If you have a bug, we can help.  If you have a design question... You should just do your own homework.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - firstly you probably want to add a BankAccount field to your form class. This is described in the question as follows:

**The class instance will need to be a private member variable of your Form. You could create it using syntax like private BankAccount bankForm.**

That would look like this:

```
public partial class BankForm : Form
{
    private BankAccount bankForm;

    public BankForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ...
```

Your 'set deposit' click should then use this field, rather than creating a local object. Something like this:

```
    private void setDepositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double setInitial = double.Parse(setDepositTextBox.Text);
        bankForm = new BankAccount(setInitial);
        listBox.Items.Add(setInitial);
    }
```

You can now perform any operations you like on this 'bankForm' field - it will persist until you do another 'initial deposit' click.

I hope this'll give you some pointers - I'm not going to write it for you, but I'm sure you don't want me to. I can clearly see you're quite keen to work yourself on this!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add functions to your BankAccount class that update the balance when you 
   deposit and withdraw money.

   ```
   public class BankAccount
   {

    public double Balance { get; private set;}

    public BankAccount() {}

    public BankAccount(double initialDeposit)
    {
        Deposit(initialDeposit);
    }

    public void Deposit(double amount)
    {
        Balance += deposit;
    }

    public void Withdraw(double amount)
    {
       Balance -= amount;
    }
   ```

   }
2. Add a BankAccount property to your BankForm and change your methods to work with the bank account property. I've re-written one of the functions for you.

```
public partial class BankForm : Form
{
    private BankAccount _bankAccount { get; set; }
```

`private void setDepositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    double deposit = double.Parse(setDepositTextBox.Text);

    if (_bankAccount = null)
    {
       _bankAccount = new BankAccount(deposit);
       listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("Initial Deposit: {0}", setDepositTextBox.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        _bankAccount.AddDeposit(deposit);
       listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("Deposit: {0}", setDepositTextBox.Text);
    }     

    listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("Balance: {0}", _bankAccount.Balance);
 }

 ...`

}

good luck!!!